# Conditionally display tick labels on axes depending on a variable

Tags: excel, vba, bar-chart

I have an excel chart Column Clustered with two series, series2 plotted on secondary axis. I try to apply John Peltier's Panel Chart trick to conditionally display tick labels on primary and secondary axis

https://peltiertech.com/excel-column-chart-primary-secondary-axes/

My problem lies with the primary axis, when I try to remove the tick labels of the axe above a given value (here 10) ("[<=10]0;;;@").
What if that value is variable?

I tried to simply replace 10 with My_variable (type Long) "[<=My_variable]0;;;@"...

...but it doesn't work at all: all the tick labels are removed
Any idea someone to make it dynamical (avoid hard-coding the threshold)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `"[<=" & My_variable & "]0;;;@"`